# How to start different instances (processes) with Firefox (win32)?

Tags: firefox, boot, process

How do you start different instances of Firefox not childthreads but new processes on Win 32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple profiles on multiple processes: [Opening a new instance of Firefox with another profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has a "Single Process" model, which basically means you cannot have multiple processes.  Read [this article](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/10/the-firefox-process-model/) for an explanation of why.

Comment: horsepuckey.  see the other answer.  this is only correct inasfar as multiple firefox processes can't access the same profile.

Comment: The program is not **intended** to run in multiple processes, but I see that it seems to be possible.

Comment: it's designed to be run on multi-user systems, simultaneously, by differing users, and has been since it was Netscape Navigator. this __requires__ multiple processes to keep user data separate.  it is most certainly intended to be used in this way.

Comment: It is not intended to have multiple processes per user, which he's obviously asking about.